# MKMapView returns bad userLocation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I checked the box in iterface builder to show user location on map and it works fine. I want to zoom the mapView to User location with using the regions and user location, but users latitude and longitude are 0.000, and app is zooming to region with center 0 and 0. Why is this?

```
CLLocation *location = [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude longitude:mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [CoreLocation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html) to get user location, and not the map.